# cloning an object in C#

Tags: c#, icloneable

I want to clone an object with using the `ICloneable` interface
and for some reason I can't clone in my program.  Here is my code:

```
public class GeoInfo : ICloneable
{
    private long InfoID;
    private string InfoName;
    private Location InfoLocation;
    private string Description;
    private InfoTypes InfoType;
    public GeoInfo(long InfoID)
    {

        this.InfoID = InfoID;
    }
    public GeoInfo(long InfoID, Location InfoLocation):this(InfoID)
    {
        this.InfoLocation = InfoLocation;
    }
    public GeoInfo(long InfoID, string InfoName, Location InfoLocation, string Description, InfoTypes InfoType):this(InfoID,InfoLocation)
    {
        this.InfoName = InfoName;
        this.Description = Description;
        this.InfoType = InfoType;
    }
    public object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        GeoInfo toReturn = new GeoInfo(InfoID, InfoName, InfoLocation, Description, InfoType);
        return (object)toReturn;
    }
```

}

Inside another class when I am trying to use the `Clone()` method, for some reason the compiler can't find the method.  Here is my other method that is trying to Clone:

```
public InfoLayer(string LayerName,List<GeoInfo> oldGeoInfos)
    {
        this.LayerName = LayerName;
        this.GeoInfos = new List<GeoInfo>();
        oldGeoInfos.ForEach((item) =>
        {
            GeoInfos.Add((GeoInfo)((ICloneable)item.Clone()));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Sidenote: You might consider making `GeoInfos` immutable then cloning becomes unnecessary. But of course I don't know if that's possible or wise in that specific case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parentheses around your cast are not correct. It should read

```
GeoInfos.Add((GeoInfo)((ICloneable)item).Clone());
```

(By the way: Why the .ForEach() ?

```
this.GeoInfos = oldGeoInfos.Select(item => ((GeoInfo)((ICloneable)item.Clone()))).ToList();
```

does the job as well.)

Answer (score 3):

As others have said you have implemented the interface explicitly.What I do is create another method that returns a typesafe version of the clone method so I tend to include.

```
public GeoInfo Clone()
{
    return new GeoInfo(InfoID, InfoName, InfoLocation, Description, InfoType);
}
```

and change the explicity implemented clone method to be (the public modifier should be removed)...

```
object ICloneable.Clone()
{
    return Clone();  //will call the public method as above
}
```

This way you don't have to cast from an object to the real type.

However there are a number of difficulties with ICloneable:

- You don't know if the clone should be a [deep or shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151520/should-i-provide-a-deep-clone-when-implementing-icloneable)
- You have to provide a mechanism for derived classes to clone itself which you can attempt to do via virtual methods. I tend to seal my classes in cases I cannot ensure proper cloning in derived types but that is a decision to be made based around your architcture and needs.

Answer (score 1):

You should only call your method

```
public object Clone()
```

**Edit:**
Or call your method

```
oldGeoInfos.ForEach((item) =>
{
    GeoInfos.Add((GeoInfo)(((ICloneable)item).Clone()));
});
```

note extra `()`.

Answer (score 0):

The line must read

```
GeoInfos.Add((GeoInfo)((ICloneable)item).Clone());
```

But consider in your `GeoInfo` class to not use explicit interface implementation (your example shouldn't compile anyway), so that it reads:

```
public object Clone()
{
    //...
}
```

Then you can simply do

```
GeoInfos.Add((GeoInfo)item.Clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented `ICloneable.Clone` explicitly, which requires that the object is cast to `ICloneable` before the method cane be called.

See [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) on MSDN.

If you want the method callable on your object, change the method declaration to:

```
public object Clone()
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep static type checking, leave your current implementation as-is, and add the following:

```
public GeoInfo Clone()
{
    return ((ICloneable)this).Clone();
}
```